# Resolving column names while reading CSV file in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, oledb, oledbconnection

I am reading `CSV` into `DataTable`. Whenever there is no column name given in `csv`, it is coming as F1, F2,F3........ I have handled that and application was running fine until client gave me another `csv` of same format and it failed. I debugged my application for client's `csv` and found that unnamed columns are comong as .NoName,.NoName1,.NoName2......

What to do to make column come unique for both files.

I have read file as below

```
public static DataTable ImportCsvFile(string filename)
        {
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
            using (OleDbConnection con =
                    new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
                    file.DirectoryName + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))            
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format
                                          ("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adp.Fill(dtExcelData);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dtExcelData;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: But the code you provided has nothing to do with column names, it should return a DataTable no matter what the column names are. Please provide the code that is **relevant** to your question.

Comment: This is the only code that fetch data into DataTable, I am not sure what changes the column name.

Comment: It doesn't matter what changed the column names. what matters is how are you handling it in your code. You wrote: *`it is coming as F1, F2,F3........ I have handled that`*. This place in the code, where you handle that, this is the **relevant** code to answer your question.

Comment: I have created table into database which holds the csv data. First time when I ran the application and debugged I was getting F1, F2, F3.... I thought it will always be same and it was till some hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column names are subject to change, you can rename them to always be F1, F2, ... Fn. Add this code to the method just before returning the dataTable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelData.Columns.Count; i++) 
{
    dtExcelData.Columns[i].ColumnName = "F" + i.ToString();
}
```